# #states can't hide/show radios in drupal 8 after form is submitted

Tags: php, drupal-8

Recently I have encountered the strange behavior of setting form created with Form `API` in Drupal 8.

I am using `#states` to hide one of the form elements `( radios )` when another element is empty. The problem is - it doesn't work with `Aggregate JavaScript files` option. After you submit the form, this element is still visible - even if condition to hide it is fulfilled.

When I disable `Aggregate JavaScript files` option, it works as expected - radios are hidden.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?